# Problem with the "stackApply" function in R

Tags: r, r-raster

I have a problem with the "stackApply" function from the raster-package. First I want to stack three raster layers (each layer has one band) - that works. And then I want to create a raster-object that shows in which of the three bands/layers the minimum value occurs (each pixel in the raster layers has a different value). But I get various error messages. Does anyone have an idea how I can solve the problem?
Thank you

```
stacktest<-stack(test,test1,test2)
min_which <- stackApply(stacktest, indices=1, fun=function(x, na.rm=NULL)which.min(x))

Error in setValues(out, v) : values must be a vector
Error in is.infinite(v) : not implemented standard method for type 'list'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible example*:

Example data from `?stackApply`

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
s <- stack(r,r,r,r,r,r)
s <- s * 1:6
```

Now use these data with your function (I removed the `na.rm=NULL` as it is not used)

```
w <- stackApply(s, indices=1, fun=function(x, ...) which.min(x) )
w
#class      : RasterLayer 
#dimensions : 10, 10, 100  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution : 36, 18  (x, y)
#extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#source     : memory
#names      : index_1 
#values     : 1, 1  (min, max)
```

Same for `which.max`

```
w <- stackApply(s, indices=1, fun=function(x, na.rm=NULL) which.max(x) )
w
# (...)
#values     : 6, 6  (min, max)
```

This suggest it works fine. In most cases that means that you probably have cells that are `NA`

```
s[1:10] <- NA
w <- stackApply(s, indices=1, fun=function(x, ...) which.min(x) )
# Error in setValues(out, v) : values must be numeric, logical or factor
```

It is easy to see why this error occurs

```
which.min(3:1) 
#[1] 3
which.min(c(3:1, NA))
#[1] 3
which.min(c(NA, NA, NA))
#integer(0)
```

If all values are `NA`, `which.min` does not return `NA` as expected. Instead it returns an empty vector. That can be fixed like this

```
which.min(c(NA, NA, NA))[1]
#[1] NA
```

And you can do

```
w <- stackApply(s, indices=1, fun=function(x, ...) which.min(x)[1] )
```

However, using `stackApply` with `indices=1` is not a good approach. You should generally use `calc` to compute cell values across all layers.

```
y <- calc(s, function(x) which.min(x)[1])
```

**But in this case you can use the more straightforward**

```
z <- which.min(s)
```